# Effective non-blocking execution

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, cloud, async-await

I implement a service which runs on cloud. I have a method `fastExcute()` which makes some calculation very fast.
I need to add to the method a call `IndependentBackgroundMethodAsync()` to other method which could be executed in background and it doesn`t really matters for when it completes its work, but it should complete!. The main thing that it will complete its work eventually 
so I thought to do:

```
fastExecute()
{
Task task = IndependentBackgroundMethodAsync();
//fast code
await t; < - could cause fastExecute not to be fast
}
```

On the other hand making a code to be :

```
fastExecute()
    {
    Task task = IndependentBackgroundMethodAsync();
    //fast code
    }
```

doesn`t promise that IndependentBackgroundMethodAsync will be executed eventually and complete its work

What is the best practice to do what I need to?

Comment: Does the method fastExecute() needs the result of background execution?

Comment: Why would you assume that `await task` will cause your method not to execute "fast"?

Comment: Also, an explanation of what "fast" actually means would be nice.

Comment: @OldFox - no, it dosn`t

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - ahalan:) IndependentBackgroundMethodAsync could take long time to execute. As far as I understand await waits until IndependentBackgroundMethodAsync comletes its ececution : so if original fastExecute takes 1ms and IndependentBackgroundMethodAsync takes 100m at total making await will cause the fastExecute to run during 100.001s

Comment: Independent.. Is a part of `fastExecute`, i don't understand what you want. Perhaps you're looking for "fire and forget" execution style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to execute your `IndependentBackgroundMethodAsync`asynchronously and you care about the result I would use `ContinueWith` (see [MSDN continuewith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx/%22ContinueWith%20MSDN%22)) 
The continuation task will be executed once your task has finished.

```
 fastExecute()
{
Task task = IndependentBackgroundMethodAsync();

task.ContinueWith(result => // handle result); 

 //fast code

}
```

Comment: I don`t care about result. I just ant it to be executed

Comment: well, then once the task is scheduled it will be executed if your service doesn't crash meanwhile. So your seccond example should work fine

Comment: I am afraid it will execute in 2years :).

Comment: The scenario which could be problematic fastExecute starts to execute IndependentBackgroundMethodAsync after that fastExecute once more and also starts IndependentBackgroundMethodAsync  when the previus one was not completed ==> to many IndependentBackgroundMethodAsync   are queued

Comment: Use a CancellationToken for your task to make sure that it doesn't exceed your time limit of execution. You can configure the task to throw an exception if it lasts longer than your limit